# Can we upload allure report in Sharepoint site using python code and share the html link in email

Tags: python, selenium, sharepoint, pytest, allure

I want to copy my allure report folder automatically to the Sharepoint site and share the link of html report to the team via email. Can we achieve this?

I do not have access of aws in my company so unable to use s3 bucket.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that you need to deal with Microsoft API - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest